# onActivityResult in zxing show results in a different activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, zxing

Hey guys im making an app using zxing integrater I have the scanner working propelry and show the results fine but would like the reslts to showon a separate class activity any ideas?

JavaActivity

```
public class QRGOLFActivity extends Activity {


TextView contents = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    contents = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contents);

}

public void doScan(View v) {
    IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(this);
}

public void onActivityResult(int request, int result, Intent i) {
    IntentResult scan = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(request,
            result, i);

    if (scan != null) {

        contents.setText(scan.getContents());
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {

    state.putString("contents", contents.getText().toString());
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {

    contents.setText(state.getString("contents"));
}

}
```

and the Xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<Button
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:onClick="doScan"
    android:text="Scan!" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contents"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="116dp"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/score"
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:text="Scorecard" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="About Us" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/contact"
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Contact Us" />
```

Comment: Accept answers for your previous questions

Answer (score 2):

Call `startActivity()` on "a separate class activity", passing whatever data you want (such as the ZXing results) via extras on the `Intent` you supply to `startActivity()`. Your "separate class activity" can then use `getIntent()` to retrieve the Intent and the various `get...Extra()` methods to retrieve those values.